# Como extraigo solo aquellas lineas de un .txt que tengan una palabra espcifica y las pego en otro .txt con python

Tags: python, python-3.x, array, regex, filereader

Saben como crear un programa en python al que tu le pases la ruta de un .txt y busque en cada linea (osea hasta cada enter) una cierta palabra (sin importar mayusculas y minusculas)
y que copie solo esas lineas pero en otro txt.

por ejemplo el siguiente txt

```
Carla: hola como estas?
Pedro: como te encuentras yo estoy bien
Carla: me escuentro haciendo algunas cosas ahora.
Marcos: Yo de momento ando desocupado
carla : Me puedes ayudar con algo?
Pedro: claro que si, por supuesto solo dime
```

Necesito que extraiga solo aquellas lineas en donde aparesca la palabra 'Carla' o 'carla', y luego escribirlas con un write() en otro txt

Lo que se me coplica es la parte de hallar las lineas y extraer la linea entera, se les ocurre algo? espero puedan ayudarme.

Comment: Lectura recomendada: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822 :)

Comment: lo puedes hacer de 2 formas, aunque no se si deba responder a una pregunta que no demuestra un trabajo de investigación.

Comment: Una publicación que simplemente dice: "este es mi ejercicio, resuélvanlo", no es bien recibida. Es mejor que incluyas el contexto (usa el botón [edit] para hacer cambios en tu pregunta): incluye que intentaste/investigaste y también cual es el problema puntual que tuviste. Demuestra algo que nos indique que formas parte de la experiencia de aprender a solucionar tu problema.

Comment: @gbianchi el tema es que ando MUY complicada con el tiempo y tenia duda para un programa que necesito, la verdad que la variedad de resoluciones  me ayuda mucho a mi a mejorar. Yo no cargue mi code porque justamente tengo poco tiempo y porque me sobreescribia la misma linea, ademas que dieron soluciones muy optimas y que ayudan mucho. Sinceramente agradesco mucho a las personas que ayudan en stack

Comment: aplica el meme de (https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4432/ser%c3%ada-posible-a%c3%b1adir-al-art%c3%adculo-c%c3%b3mo-elaboro-una-buena-pregunta-indicacion/4433#4433) XD

Comment: Los problemas con tu tiempo, no son problemas del sitio. Y ninguna de las respuestas, ayuda a nadie mas que vos. Al no tener ni una linea de codigo, nadie aprendio nada. Si hubieras puesto tu codigo, podriamos haberte dicho como mejorar tu codigo, como entender tus errores, como aprender a hacerlo mejor. De esta forma, solo copiaste un codigo que arregla el problema...

Comment: @gbianchi creo que tu comentario puede resultar un poco ofensivo, seria mejor decir "para que tu pregunta sirva de ayuda a los demas es bueno que demuestre un trabajo de investigacion, ese tipo de preguntas es bien reccibido en StackOverflow"

Comment: @gbianchi soy conciente de que no pero que quieres que te diga necesitaba ayuda, y me ayudaron muy bien. Encerio que no encuentro problemas con eso (sin contar que el tema queda y sirve para otros)

Comment: @Christian eso se lo comente varios comentarios mas arriba

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creo que no es nada dificil hacerlo, solo debes de investigar un poco sobre la lectura de archivos.

```py
#abrimos el archivo y leemos por lineas
with open('file1.txt') as f:
    #nos devuelve una lista con las lineas
    lineas = f.readlines()
    with open('escribir.txt','a') as e:
        for linea in lineas:
             #verificamos 
            if 'carla' in linea.lower():
                #escribimos
                e.write(linea)
```

Tambien se puede hacer con expresiones regulares

```py
import re

with open('file1.txt') as f:
    lineas = f.readlines()
    #esto crea una expresion regular
    #el re.I indica que no diferencia mayusculas y minusculas
    regex = re.compile(r'carla', re.I) 
    with open('escribir.txt','a') as e:
        #recorremos
        for linea in lineas:
            if regex.match(linea):
                #escribimos
                e.write(linea)
```

Tambien podemos buscar un nombre de forma "dinamica" solo cambiamos una linea

```py
with open('file1.txt') as f:
...
    name = r"carla"
    regex = re.compile(name, re.I)
```

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/124498/discussion-on-answer-by-christian-como-extraigo-solo-aquellas-lineas-de-un-txt).

Answer (score 1):

Suponiendo que quieras leer del fichero *leer.txt* y escribir en *escribir.txt* puedes hacerlo de la siguiente manera:

```py
fileLeer = open('leer.txt', 'r')
fileEscribir = open("escribir.txt", "w")

lines = fileLeer.readlines()
 
for line in lines:
    # if line.lower().find("carla") != -1:
    if "carla" in line.lower():
        fileEscribir.write(line)

fileLeer.close()
fileEscribir.close()
```

Comment: cada vez que abres un archivo, debes de cerrarlo, puedes evitar eso con un `with`

Comment: @Fran muchas gracias por cierto porque pones el -1 ?

Comment: En lugar de usar find para hayar una subcadena en una cadena, es mejor usar el operador in. Es decir cambiar esto `if line.lower().find("carla") != -1:` por esto `if "carla" in line.lower():`

Comment: @Christian tienes razón, se me paso. Electrisik, `find()` devuelve -1 en caso de que no lo encuentre. Si pongo `!= -1` le indico los casos en los que si lo ha encontrado

Comment: Muchas gracias por la ayuda